# qsort an array of structs in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, qsort

I'm attempting to sort an array of structs in a struct based on an int value. I've successfully sorted an array of structs but I'm guessing I'm passing a wrong value somewhere for the nested structs.

I just need the structs in the array sorted the value of a.

The structs are set up as:

```
struct s2{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct s1{
    int c;
    struct s2 arr[10];
}
```

I have a compare function:

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b){

    struct s1 *q1 = (struct s1 *)a;
    struct s1 *q2 = (struct s1 *)b;

    return(q1->arr->a - q2->arr->a); 
}
```

And I call qsort:

```
struct s1 myStruct; 
size_t theLen = sizeof(myStruct.arr) / sizeof(struct s2);
qsort(myStruct.arr, 10, theLen, comp);
```

For the input:

```
10, 5, 7, 20, 17, 9, 3, 11, 15, 1
```

I get output:

```
2147451181, 589824, 327680, 65536, 131072, 4, 5, 11, 15, 8
```

I'm guessing it may be something to do with how I declare the length?

Thanks!

The file line is:

```
10 5 7 20 17 9 3 11 15 1
```

myStruct.arr[i].a is filled from file input using fgets and sscanf:

```
fgets(t, sizeof(t), fp);
sscanf(t, "%d,...,%d", &myStruct.arr[0].a,...,&myStruct.arr[9].a);
```

myStruct.arr[i].b is filled with a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    myStruct.arr[i].b = i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes with your code

1. You are using `q1->arr->a` to compare where you should use `q1->a` (where `q1` is of type `const struct s2`). This has also been explained by @GauravSehgal in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47149978/2858773)
2. If you look at the third argument to [qsort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm), it is acutally the size of each element to compare in bytes. But you have passed the number of elements. Change your call to -

   `qsort(myStruct.arr, 10, sizeof(struct s2), comp);`

and you should get the desired result.

There are some other points you need to take care of (pointed out by @Stargateur) -

1. Declare `q1` and `q2` to be of type `const struct s2*`, because you do not want to discard the `const` qualifier.
2. Do not cast `a` and `b` explicitly while assigning to `q1` and `q2` because they are of type `const void*` which auto-promotes to pointer of any const type.

Comment: I will add that OP cast is wrong (and useless cause `void const *` is auto promote) because it's discard const qualifier: should be `struct s2 const *q1 = a; struct s1 const *q2 = b;`

Answer (score 1):

```
qsort(myStruct.arr, 10, theLen, comp);
```

You are sorting `myStruct.arr` here where each element is of type `struct s2`.So your compare should be

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b){

struct s2 *q1 = (struct s2 *)a;
struct s2 *q2 = (struct s2 *)b;

return(q1->a - q2->a); 
}
```

EDIT: the third parameter to `qsort` is the size of each element of array to be sorted.So it should be

```
qsort(myStruct.arr, theLen, sizeof(struct s2), comp);
```

Comment: This definitely makes more sense than what I had, but unfortunately, it's still giving random output: 4, 589824, 11, 65551, 131072, 65536, 5, 196608, 0, 17. I shouldn't say random... it's the same output every time.

Comment: You need to show your complete code where you are filling `myStruct.arr`